# convert matrix to data frame

Tags: r, matrix

I have 5x5 matrix:

```
mat <- structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.833333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
```

I want to convert into data frame with 3 columns : to (values = 1,2,3,4,5), from (values = 1,2,3,4,5), weight (values = e.g. 0.833333333333333,  0.166666666666667, etc.)

I try many ways but no luck (result is not correct):

```
from_id <- rep(1:5, each = 5)
to_id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
weights <- as.vector(mat)

edges_df <- data.frame(from = from_id, to = to_id, weight = weights)
edges_df <- edges_df[edges_df$weight != 0, ]
```

For exmple - in 5th row, 5->3 should be the only weight... 5->1 = 5 ->2 = 5 -> 3 = 5 -> 4 = 0.

How I can do this?

Comment: `data.frame(from = c(col(mat)), to = c(row(mat)), weights = c(mat))[mat > 0, ]`

Comment: What does your expected answer look like?

Comment: thx everyone! in 5th row, 5->3 should be the only weight... 5->1 = 5 ->2 = 5 -> 3 = 5 -> 4 = 0

Comment: `subset(as.data.frame.table(mat), Freq>0)`